# Hadoop integration with web application

Tags: hadoop

I want to consume a user selected file in Hadoop, through given user interface. What should be the approach, is it is a wise decision to use Hadoop in web

Comment: This question is very general and not very clear. please describe what you try to achieve.
Do you mean let the user upload a file from a web interface, and process the file using hadoop?

Comment: Yes absolutely, I am using Struts framework for uploading a file and consuming that in Hadoop. Is it right thing to do ? Whenever I am trying to run my Hadoop job, ClassNotFoundException is coming for Mapper and Reducer class.

Comment: @PiyushSharma Hi Piyush, Could you pls share how did you interface the struts app with hadoop? Which API/tools you used to access hadoop/hdfs data in your web app and vice versa? Was the web server inside hadoop cluster or outside cluster talking over http etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues - If you should use hadoop, and how to use hadoop.

1. the typical file you can expect a user uploading through a web interface is much smaller then the data size where hadoop begins to be relevant.

So it's very probable that hadoop isn't the right choice for this scenario

1. It's hard to know what the problem is without more detailed logs.
   But the most common case, if the class that isn't found is your class (and not an infrastructure class) is that you need to distribute your jars to all the hadoop tasks.

a simple solution is to use the -libjars parameter when running your application

see a good explanation [here](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/)

Comment: For your first point I agree, but my requirement is like Hadoop should be able to consume all JBoss log files in it. At first trying to upload a single file after that we will automate it to consume all Jboss log files

Comment: I have added "conf.set("mapred.jar","/path/hadoop.jar");" in my code. It is working fine now